# How to auto get my country currency symbol with out mentioning the country in kotlin android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

**I am using this code but it return usd=$ instead of pkr=Rs I wanted to get Rs without mention my country or currency**

```
val currency: Currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault())
               
             val symbol: String = currency.symbol
```

Comment: How can the program read your mind and know which currency you want to pick? You have to tell it.

Comment: but the program read my phones currency setting and also can check my local currency.

Comment: @Tenfour04 okay if i have country's currency for example PKR then how can I get "Rs" which is the symbol of PKR.

Comment: `Currency.getInstance("PKR")` or `Currency.getInstance(Locale("en", "pk"))` should work, but either way, it's returning "PKR". I can't get it to return Rs. I don't know how they determine what the correct currency symbol is if there is more than one way to write it. `Locale.getDefault()` gives the region and language chosen by the user in the Android settings, so that should work unless your device isn't set to your country. If it's the emulator in Android Studio, maybe it defaults to the USA.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes, you are right. Currency.getInstance("PKR") also return PKR instead of Rs. therefore now i am using if statement when the user's currency is in PKR then return  Rs using if statement.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, It will work using your device telephony manager.

Here is the working code, You gave to get the county code.

```
fun Context.getDeviceCountryCode(): String {
    var countryCode: String?
    val tm = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    countryCode = tm.simCountryIso
    if (countryCode != null && countryCode.length == 2) return countryCode.lowercase()
    countryCode = if (tm.phoneType == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA) {
        getCDMACountryIso()
    } else {
        tm.networkCountryIso
    }
    if (countryCode != null && countryCode.length == 2) return countryCode.lowercase()
    countryCode = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        resources.configuration.locales[0].country
    } else {
        resources.configuration.locale.country
    }
    return if (countryCode.length == 2) countryCode.lowercase() else "us"
}
```

After that call this method for getting the currency symbol

```
fun getCurrencySymbol(currencyCode: String?): String? {
    val currencySymbol: String?
    if (currencyCode == null || currencyCode.isEmpty()) {
        currencySymbol = currencyCode
    } else {
        val currencyLocale: Locale?
        val currencyLocaleMap: Map<Currency?, Locale>?
        val currency: Currency?
        try {
            currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode)
            currencyLocaleMap = getCurrencyLocaleMap()
            currencyLocale = currencyLocaleMap[currency]
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            return "$"
        }
        currencySymbol = if (currency != null && currencyLocale != null) {
            currency.getSymbol(currencyLocaleMap[currency])
        } else {
            currencyCode
        }
    }
    return currencySymbol
}
```

Here are the calling methods, you can call that method and the method will be return the currency code, According to your device.

```
 countryCurrencySysmbol = getCurrencyIcon(getDeviceCountryCode())
```